# Best and optimized way to create web based Interactive Choropleth Map

Tags: web, d3.js, openlayers, gis, leaflet

I am going to build an interactive Choropleth map for Bangladesh. The goal of this project is to build a map system and populate different type of data. I read the documentations of the Openlayers, Leaflet and D3. I need some advice to find the right path. The solution must be optimized enough.

The map i am going to create will be something like the following http://nasirkhan.github.io/bangladesh-gis/asset/base_files/bd_admin_3.html. It is prepared based on leaflet js. But it is not mandatory to work with this library. I tried with Leaflet because it is easy to use and found the expected solution within a very short time.

The requirement of the project is to prepare a Choropleth map where i can display the related data. for example i have to show the population of all the divisions of Bangladesh. at the same time there should be some options so that i can show the literacy rate, male-female ratio and so on.

the solution i am working now have some issues. like the load time is huge and if i want to load the 2nd dataset then i have to load the same huge geolocation data, how can i optimize or avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet has a layers control feature. If you cut down your data to just what is required, split it into different layers and allow the user to select that layers they are interested in viewing that might cut down on the loading of the data. Another option is to simplify the shape of the polygons.